# AWS : Deploy Github branch instead of commits

Tags: git, amazon-web-services, aws-code-deploy

I am working on automation of deployments. We have a requirement where it's required to deploy specific branches master/testing/dev etc from github to AWS.

I tried with CodeDeploy, which is working, but it requires a commit-id always. Is it possible with AWS to deploy a specific branch from Github. It would be better if it's from AWS management console as non-technical users are also deploying. Thank you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Deploying a specific branch using AWS CodeDeploy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35041475/deploying-a-specific-branch-using-aws-codedeploy)